# Two SQL counts without nested select

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have an SQL query I need to change not to be nested selects.

I'm not sure how to do it....

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT _user_id) FROM [data] WHERE (_language == 'en')) / 
    COUNT(DISTINCT _user_id)
FROM [data]
```

Preferably not with 'JOIN' (unless there's no other way).

EDIT:
I need the ratio between users who uphold the condition and those who don't

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you share some sample data and the expected result please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN _language = 'en' THEN _user_id END)) /
        COUNT(DISTINCT _user_id)
       )
FROM data;
```

The question is tagged MySQL, and yet you are using square braces -- this will cause an error in MySQL.  You don't need the square braces anyway.  The standard equality comparison is `=`, not `==` (even if bigquery supports both).

Comment: That's not good... I need ratio of the users between those who uphold the condition and those who don't... this doesn't seem to do so.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! THANKS! (need to wait 8 minutes until I'll accept it)

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would do it if I wanted to distinct on more than 1 variable?

Comment: If you are using MySQL, you would just do `count(distinct col1, col2)`.  In Bigquery, you would concatenate the fields together for the calculation.  Do note that bigquery does an approximate `count(distinct)`, so be careful using it in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inline `case` expression:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _language = 'en' THEN _user_id ELSE NULL END) / 
       COUNT(DISTINCT _user_id)
FROM   [data]
```